# Google Web Toolkit auto refresh grid

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I implementing an application that has a grid in it and everytime someone changes something on this grid it automaticaly updates the grid for others who has the grid opened (something like what the google docs does).

I tried implementing this using gwt-rpc sending a request every 2 seconds and if there is something new the application just send what has changed. But I had some bad results when uploaded to the GAE server.

So I decided to analyze the google docs implementation and a saw that it keeps a open connection for almost one minute and send some new information everytime someones changes something. I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this on GWT. I'm trying to do it now using the request factory but I think I'll face the same problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use GAE you might want to look at [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html).

There is also [gwt-gae-channel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/), which is a GWT wrapper around Channel API's javascript client.

Comment: Have you ever used this gwt-gae-channel? I'm trying to use it bug it seems to be a litle bit buggy. Do you have any examples using it?

Comment: The Channel API definitely is the best solution and very fast. But the gwt implementation gwt-gae-channel has some issues. I found this one gwt-channel-api http://code.google.com/p/gwt-channel-api/ that is more stable but doesn't implement all the events. So I think I'll code my own client side implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out what the GWT folks gave to say about using [push technology with GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)

Comment: Server push does not work on AppEngine because requests are limited to 30 seconds.